# SQL Database Connection from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, database-connection, connection-string

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, but I am getting an error:

> The server was not found or was not accessible.

Here is the code for connection string builder:

```
private static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{     
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = Environment.MachineName + "\\abc-hp";
    builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    builder.InitialCatalog = "MyDB";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);

    return conn;
}
```

Server Name used to login to SQL Server Management Studio: `abc-hp`

Database Name: `MyDB`

Comment: Is your `SQL server browser service` running?

Comment: No, SQL Server Browser is not running.

Comment: Can you try after turning it on?

Comment: How to turn it on?

Comment: Also to ask: is SQL Server running on your local machine or another place on the network?

Comment: [Here you go](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165734(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: SQL Server is running on my machine. I am using local database.

Comment: I have started SQL Server Browser but it still don't work. :(

Comment: Findout your `instances`. Open `SQL Server Configuration Manager`, there will be something like `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS )` or `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` or may be your custom named instance. Make sure that instance `SQL Server (xxx)` is running.

Comment: Instance Name: SQL Server (myName) is running and SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) is not running.

Comment: Change your datasource to `Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName`

Comment: Still doesn't work after doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it has to do with your `builder.DataSource = Environment.MachineName + "\\abc-hp";` line.

Try this instead:

`builder.DataSource = "abc-hp";`

Comment: is there an instance name?

Comment: Where to check that?